# Common statistics used to evaluate teams/players in competition

Tags: analysis, statistics, game-theory

**Background**

We have a little smash game tournament* at work, and we have been recording statistics, some of them have already been surprising and I would like to glean some more facts from the data, but I have ran out of ideas. Here is the spreadsheet with the stats:

[Character Stats](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MlYG5ArkwY_Oq4l755ipB3nzMHL1f4xF1Njkxm9HKus/edit?usp=sharing)

We have got things like

- Most Consistent Winning Team
- Character Win Percentage
- etc

But all of these feel like they are hiding the more interesting statistics. For example, 'Captain Falcon' has the highest win percentage but he has only played 1 game. I feel like there is a fairer statistic that would take this into account but I can't think of what. Also the pairings are really interesting and I feel I should dive more into that but not sure what formulas to use on them

*the tournament consists of a human player pairing with a CPU player vs another team of human player and CPU player.

**Question**

Which leads me to my question, in situations where there are multiple points of data (e.g. goals, matches played, matches won, team mates etc). what type of statistics are usually used to evaluate the best 'player'/'dream team' or even the player/team with the most 'potential'.

For example, with our stats above Captain Falcon looks great by **win percentage** but in the **single** Captain Falcon battle he won 5-6, so he was one stock from being eliminated himself. Do things like football take this sort of thing into account for example

- Does it evaluate teams on the best 'Goal Margin'
- How a team plays *with* a player vs without that player
- Conversely how a Player plays with another team vs their own
- Which team set up a particular team struggles most with

(Not looking for the *best*, that would be objective, but a list of the common approaches would be really interesting :) )